# c# Format exception was unhandled

Tags: parsing, exception, format, int, streamreader

I have a method that fills up the elements of an int[,]. The elements that need to be filled are stored in a .txt file like this:

```
 1
 1
 2
 2
```

Meaning that I have to fill up the [1,1] and [2,2] element.

For this I use this but it gives the error above

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    x = int.Parse(SR.ReadLine());
    y = int.Parse(SR.ReadLine());
    mezo.mezo[x, y] = 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: x = int.Parse(SR.ReadLine().Trim());

Comment: Can you show what SR.ReadLine() returns for you?

Comment: It returns this: when converting a string to datetime parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.

Comment: On your edit promotion: I won't edit the text because it is important that each number is in a new line.

Comment: @user3576186 : That is the exception you are getting. Assign the value of `SR.ReadLine()` to a string variable and please show what that string variable contains. `string s = SR.ReadLine();`

Comment: I Console.WriteLine'd the shit out of it, and know I know what the problem is. After 1 1 2 2 I have a '!!!!' separator, and it goes on and trying to read that. I don't know why is it doing that since the for should stop that from goin over the 4 digits.

Comment: I see the error. It reads all the lines for some reason, not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN(`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/b3h1hf19.aspx`) a `FormatException` is thrown when:

> s is not in the correct format.

s in your case is `SR.ReadLine()` which is returning some value that is not recognized as a number format.

At first look it might be because of whitespaces in your file.

Try

`SR.ReadLine().Trim()`

OR

`NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite` for the number style in the `Parse` method.